# How to link html artifacts with href in jenkins

Tags: html, jenkins, hyperlink, ref, artifacts

I run some jenkins jobs to execute regressiontests on an other VM via the agent.
As result I receive in Jenkins artifacts: one RegressionTestRun.html and a lot of testrun files
The RegressionTestRun file is an overview includes html links to the single testrun files:

RegressionTestRun.html
testrun_1599.html
testrun_1600.html
testrun_1601.html

When opening my regressiontest file it has the url
https://jenkins.xxx.net/job/stmt-automation-regressiontest-VM38-AMA/**lastSuccessfulBuild**/artifact/RegressionTestRun.html

or url with build number:
https://jenkins.airplus.net/job/stmt-automation-regressiontest-VM38-AMA/**30**/artifact/RegressionTestRun_AMA_create_statement-20230725-1808.html

I guess the html links need to be relative, but with each try I get "about:blank#blocked"
How does the link has to look like?

It is the company jenkins, so I have no rights to install any addOns or plugIns.
Hope some has an idea.
Thanks Jochen

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was in the href it self.
This is the correct link:
testrun_2176.html